# Chrome Extension permissions field in the manifest.json

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying narrow the scope of permission, so that I don't have to do the following in the manifest file.

"permissions": ["http://*.google.com/", "https://*.google.com/"],

However, the authentication requires www.google.com, login.google.com and more.

My first question would be: is having "http://*.google.com/", "https://*.google.com/" in the permissions field a bad practice?

If yes, what are my options? I looked at using "identity", but does it apply to extensions as well?

Comment: Are you using the Identity API (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity)? The -extension tag on this question suggests not, but if you are, declaring the identity permission automatically grants the needed host permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your question. Please provide more details about what you really want. So, I firstly give some info, maybe it right.

Use:

```
"permissions": ["*://*.google.com/"]
```

Pages accepted:

- http://www.google.com
- https://www.google.com
- http://login.google.com
- https://login.google.com
- And so on...

Use:

```
"permissions": ["*://www.google.com/"]
```

Page accepted:

- http://www.google.com
- https://www.google.com

You can get more info in [Chrome Extension Pattern](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) page.